# How to change the active state default color "blue"

Tags: jquery-mobile

I was trying to change the .active state's default color. Tried changing in the .ui-btn-active. Didn't work. Any ideas?? Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/cnMdb/31/)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try adding it as the last rule, with the !important clause:

```
.ui-btn-active { color: red !important; background: none !important; background-color: green !important;  }
```

Worked fine here on your jsFiddle.

Comment: background is ok.  for color of text with !important and not applied :(

Answer (score 0):

This worked with your jsFiddle example:

```
.ui-header .ui-navbar li a:active {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```